# Log4j2 rolling file overwrites existing log

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have the following configuration file for Log4j2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error" name="D3Hooks" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile append="true" name="RollingFile" fileName="D:\temp\logs\hooks.log" filePattern="hooks.log.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log">
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %level %c.%m %ex{full} %n"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What I expect from this configuration is that a new log file is created daily and 30 log files are kept. What happens instead is that there is only one log file which is overwritten daily. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy you should set interval="1" and modulate="true".

See also [Time based triggering policy in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19304165/3021395)

Comment: I just tried it out, now the log is appended to the existing file.

Comment: Sorry interval should be 1 instead of 24.

Answer (score 0):

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %level %c.%m %ex{full} %n"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

The log file will create 1 file per day which the interval setting equal to 1 when the pattern layout with pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd}. Because the interval is dependent to the log file name format. If the file name have something like `HH:mm:ss` it will create a file per second.