# Log4j: Null object returned for IfLastModified in Delete

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to use TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for RollingFileAppender. Log4J (v2.18) is throwing NullPointerException due to AGE.

**Error:**

```
2023-01-12 08:05:00,903 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfLastModified for element IfLastModified: java.lang.NullPointerException: age java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: age
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfLastModified.<init>(IfLastModified.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfLastModified.createAgeCondition(IfLastModified.java:105)
    ... 23 more
```

**Log4j.properties file:**

```
name= RollingFileLogConfig
appenders = console, rolling

# Log files location
property.basePath = ./logs

# Console appender
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}/app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 10MB
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Configure root logger
rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout, rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

I have tried changing file pattern as mentioned in other [similar questions asked in stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304165/time-based-triggering-policy-in-log4j2) but still getting the same error.

Comment: Your configuration does not have the **required** property `age` in the `IfLastModified` condition. Since the error message is not really helpful, I reported this as [issue#1231](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1231).